# Show a div if a cookie exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, hide

So... I've been trying to show an element for recurrent visitors to my site.

This is how I'm trying to do it: (you can [see this JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Magne/u1fen8kd/48/) as well)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // If the 'show cookie is set we show the message
  if (!readCookie('show')) {
    $('#hide').show();
  }
  else {
    $("#hide").hide();
    createCookie("show", true, 1);
  }
  return false;
});
```

And I'm also using this cookie functions that I took from w3schools

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
  if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
  }
  else var expires = "";
  document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
  var nameEQ = name + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
  }
  return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
  createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

However, it's not working and I'm pretty sure it has something to do with my JQuery attempt, just not sure where my mistake is.

Thanks for any help!

---Edit Update---
Following some advices, this is what I've got now:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function(){
        if(Cookies.get('previsitor')) {
          $('#atc').show(1000);
        }
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="atc" style="display: none">
      <a href="#">Something I want to hide</a>
    </div>
    <script>
      Cookies.set ("previsitor","true",{ expires: 1 });
      alert(document.cookie);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm using this library for my cookie management: https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

However, it's still not doing what I want, I'm usin the `alert(document.cookie);` and looks like the cookie is not being created at all... but why!? :(

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Well, is not showing it. It stays hidden.

Comment: Did you copy that javascript content directly? Your missing alot of brackets?

Comment: Can you also post your HTML or at least the relevant parts? I suspect your jQuery selector might not be selecting the right element. Unless of course the ID of the element you want to show and hide is called hide that is.

Comment: @GrandIQ I don't see any missing brackets, which ones are you not seeing?

Comment: Sure, it's just this:
<div id="hide">
<a href="#">Something I want to hide</a>
</div>

Comment: @AdamH Can you write an if statement or while without using curly brackets? Edit: I can't believe I never knew this, I thought { } are 100% necessary! Apologies

Comment: No worries @GrandIQ, it's handy and i use it all the time for single line loops too.

Comment: @MagneRaknaren you never set the cookie so it is always nothing so it never goes into your else, it always calls $('#hide').show().

Comment: @AdamH Isn't this "createCookie("show", true, 1);" setting the cookie? Could you show me with an example please? thanks!

Comment: @MagneRaknaren yes, that function call _should_ set the cookie but it's never called. If you attach your debugger and step through you will notice that it never gets to that section of code. readCookie('show') is always false so it never goes into your else block and call createCookie("show", true, 1);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. This should do the trick.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //pass cookie name 
    if(checkCookie('the_cookies')){
      $('#atc').show();  
    }
    else{
      $('#atc').hide();
    }

    function checkCookie($name)
    {
      if (typeof $.cookie($name) === 'undefined'){
        // set cookie if not exists
        $.cookie($name, 'the_value');
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: This works! http://jsfiddle.net/Magne/hyarp12s/2/

Thanks... I'm not sure what's the difference besides the "return true"

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create your cookie after the if/else block

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // If the 'show cookie is set we show the message
  if (!readCookie('show')) {
    $('#hide').show();
  }
  else {
    $("#hide").hide();
  }
  createCookie("show", true, 1);
});
```

Previously, the createCookie function wasn't being called at all since it was nested in the false condition.

Answer (score 0):

Change calling

```
if (readCookie('show')) {
$('#hide').show();
 }
else {
$("#hide").hide();
createCookie("show", true, 1);
}
return false;
});
```

Change this function

```
function readCookie(name) {
 var nameEQ = name + "=";
 var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
 for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
var c = ca[i];
while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) 
{alert(nameEQ.length,c.length);
return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);}
}
return false;
}
```

This should work!